# TestnNG Error: No sourcedir was specified

Tags: eclipse, command-line, testng, appium

Getting Error while trying to execute testNG Class from Command Line Argument on Windows.

> Exception in thread "main" org.testng.TestNGException: No sourcedir
>   was specified
>           at org.testng.TestNG.checkConditions(TestNG.java:1170)
>           at org.testng.TestNG.privateMain(TestNG.java:1010)
>           at org.testng.TestNG.main(TestNG.java:997)

Comment: Please add your code for the target that runs the testng task, and the code in the testng xml that your target is using.

Comment: hello Friend, I am not getting what exactly you meant to say.Please let me know in detail.

Comment: Are you trying to run testng directly from command line or using Ant/Maven?

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are following correct TestNG command-line syntax as mentioned in [documentation](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng)

**Syntax:**

```
java org.testng.TestNG testng1.xml [testng2.xml testng3.xml ...]
```

You may have to use `-sourcedir` command line switch if the test has java doc comments in it.

`-sourcedir`

**Usage:** 
*The directories where your javadoc annotated test sources are. This option is only necessary if you are using javadoc type annotations. (e.g. "src/test" or "src/test/org/testng/eclipse-plugin;src/test/org/testng/testng").*